# Notify item update by JavaScript

Tags: development, javascript, client-object-model

I created a popup window that updated the metadata information of my item.
When the operation of updating is complete I would like to close my popup and show the notify alert.

I succeed to close the dialog but I don't succeed to show the SP.UI.notify.

Can you help me?

Comment: I forgot that I changed the default master page with my custom

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
OpenPopUpPage('/', function() {
  SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Closed...');
});
```

Comment: I have the SP.UI.Notify.addNotification... maybe I have a problem with my master page. The div for the notify is inside the code.

Comment: Do you have `<div id="notificationArea" class="s4-noti"></div>` in your masterpage? I'm not sure if location matters, but under `#s4-ribbonrow` should do the trick

Comment: yes it's... but the notify doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

Could you check to see if either of the code snippets below helps you to get the job done?

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("YOURMESSAGE", false); },"sp.js");
```

or

```
parent.ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
parent.SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("YOURMESSAGE", false); },"sp.js");
```

Also be sure to check for JavaScript errors by using a debugger. (In IE you can do it by enabling the "Developer Tools" feature and pressing "start debugging" button in the Script tab, In Firefox you can use the Firebug plugin) :)